# how can i stop two or multiple people booking the same parking slot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Parking Slot Reservation System. My project is working properly but I am facing one problem when ever user request slot it first check slot status if slot status is free then it move user to next reservation activity but problem is that if two or multiple user try at the same time then all move to next reservation activity and all reserve one slot at same time. I want only one user will be Able to reserve slot at one time . Here is my code

```
DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parkingslots").child(slotkey);

if(reference.child("status").equals("free")) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("car_number", cnumber);
    map.put("date", d + "/" + m + "/" + y);
    map.put("entrance_time", h1 + ":" + m1 + ":" + am_pm1);
    map.put("exit_time", h2 + ":" + m2 + ":" + am_pm2);
    map.put("payment_status", "pending");
    map.put("slot_id", slotkey);
    map.put("user_id", uid);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("booking").push();
    ref.setValue(map);

    reference.child("status").setValue("booked");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Slot Booked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(Booking.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Slot just booked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(Booking.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Hey Sami. It looks like your question attracted some downvotes. I'm not sure why that is, since it seems like a reasonable question. I provide an answer below, so let me know if that all makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to:

1. [Use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) in your client-side code, to ensure only one client can ever claim the parking spot.
2. [Use security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) on the server, that only the owner can overwrite an existing reservation.

Comment: can you please explain your answer how can i add new value by using transaction. I see documentation but that only about updating value with the help of transaction.

Comment: A transaction always first reads the document it updates, so it should be pretty straightforward. If you're having trouble making the transaction work, it's easiest to help if you show what you've already tried.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any transaction, so I recommend starting from the example in the documentation I linked, or one of the many other [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+realtime+database+android+transaction) out there. I would also recommend using the values that need to be unique to construct the database key, instead of generating a random on with `push()`. Only by having repeatable (idempotent) keys can you guarantee uniqueness.